# Detail viewset for product in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-viewsets

I need to get just one product object in my VeiwSet based on a given slug, I looked into the docs, but I can't find any solution to this problem. I need to get the slug from the url path aswell, but I don't know how to do it too. Obviously the code below doesn't work.

product/serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Product

class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    image = serializers.ImageField(required=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ("name", "description", "slug", "id", "price", "stock", "image", "category")
```

product/views.py

```
from django.http.response import JsonResponse
from rest_framework import serializers, viewsets
from rest_framework.response import Response
from django.http import JsonResponse
from .serializers import ProductSerializer
from .models import Product

class ProductViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Product.objects.all().order_by('name')
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer

class ProductDetailViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet, slug):
    queryset = Product.objects.filter(slug=slug)
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
```

product/urls.py

```
from rest_framework import routers, urlpatterns
from django.urls import path, include
from .views import ProductViewSet, ProductDetailiewSet

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'', ProductViewSet)


urlpatterns = [
    path('<str:slug>/',),
    path('', include(router.urls))
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ViewSets` allows you to combine `ListView` and `DetailView` into one view.
So you don't need two different views to handle the both actions.

Now if you want to use slug in the url instead of the `id` by default, you just have to specify `lookup_field` in the serializer and the view like this :

**serializers.py**

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    image = serializers.ImageField(required=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ("name", "description", "slug", "id", "price", "stock", "image", "category")
        lookup_field = 'slug'
        extra_kwargs = {
            'url': {'lookup_field': 'slug'}
        }
```

**views.py**

```
class ProductViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Product.objects.all().order_by('name')
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    lookup_field = 'slug'
```

**urls.py**

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'', ProductViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'', include(router.urls)),
]
```

Now you can query `http://localhost:8000/` for **products list** and `http://localhost:8000/product_slug` for **product detail** with `product_slug` as slug.
More about [Django ViewSets and Routers](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/6-viewsets-and-routers/)